# How to disable/redirect shopping cart page to checkout page

Tags: magento2.3, checkout

I'm using magento 2.3.X , how can i disable/redirect shopping cart page to checkout page.
now is httsp://xxx.com/checkout/cart/ but i want to skip checkout/cart change to checkout page.

Thank you!